# How to get Files Notifications and Activities links in the new Master Detail Programs Developed in Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

In Acumatica T100 shows how to develop the Master Detail Program. The requirement is to have Files, Notifications and Activities (links at top) in every Entry Screen have to be kept in any new form for consistency.

How can these links and Functionality be added in new Forms developed in Acumatica using the same database elements !

Any documentation available ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include a NoteID field in your DAC and in the Form indicate which options you want available.

For example looking at the sales order page you can see it has the NoteIndicator, FilesIndicator,LinkIndicator, and ActiivityIndicator property all set to true in PXFormView. This will add the buttons in the upper right area of your page.

```
<px:PXFormView ID="form" runat="server" DataSourceID="ds" Style="z-index: 100" Width="100%" DataMember="Document" Caption="Order Summary"
    NoteIndicator="True" FilesIndicator="True" LinkIndicator="True" EmailingGraph="PX.Objects.CR.CREmailActivityMaint,PX.Objects"
    ActivityIndicator="True" ActivityField="NoteActivity" DefaultControlID="edOrderType" NotifyIndicator="True"
    TabIndex="14900">
```

**FYI:** When using a projection DAC in a grid, you might be required to add NoteIndicator="True" FilesIndicator="True" to the grid to get the icons/columns to show up and work.

Comment: Thanks Brendan, RussianDev - Worked for Note, Activities but user is not able to upload files. Is there any security issue with files ??

Answer (score 1):

In Acumatica NoteID is the global data record identifier required for full-text search and to enter textual note or upload files to a data record. Below is the declaration of the NoteID field. Once you define NoteID field in your DAC, it will automatically support textual notes and attachments:

```
public abstract class noteID : PX.Data.IBqlField
{
}
[PXNote()]
public virtual Guid? NoteID { get; set; }
```